# Why is MySQL Data Connector taking so much longer than MySQL Query Browser?

Tags: mysql

I have a very simple query (three where conditions; two equals, one between) from a single table and in MySQL Query Browser the query takes less than half a second to run, returning 8300 records. If I run the exact same query using the MySQL Data Connector (really just an OLEDB wrapper), it takes about 35 seconds.

The engine being used is MyISAM (if that matters). I'm using Visual Studio 2008 (also, if that matters). Edit: Using MySQL Data Connector 5.2.5. Edit, edit: Switching to MySQL Data Connector 6.0.3 (the latest) shaved it down to 29 seconds.

The query is:

```
select drh_data.reading_time, drh_data.raw_value, drh_data.float_value, drh_data.data_quality
from drh_data
where drh_data.site_id=202
and drh_data.device_id=7
and reading_time between '2009-04-08 11:15:01' and '2009-05-08 11:15:02'
order by drh_data.reading_time desc;
```

Any ideas?

Update: I finally got around to checking CPU usage (as suggested by an answerer) and found that 50% CPU time is used by my application. The VirtualPC box that's running MySQL (in CentOS) had 0% during those 20 (or so) seconds, so the problem is all on the client side. I also ran an Explain on the query, which came back with the following:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys                               key                             key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  drh_data    range   PRIMARY,idx_site_device_reading_receive     idx_site_device_reading_receive 11                  7674    Using where
```

I'm tapped out here. Does anyone have any ideas to resolve this? I'm about to resort to breaking up the selects via LIMIT, but I don't think I should have to do that.

Comment: Oh, lovely. This turned out to be a DataGridView issue, not a MySQL query issue. It took so much longer to load because the DataGridView had to resize each cell in a row EVERY TIME A ROW WAS ADDED, because I had set the AutoSizeRowsMode to AllCells. It's now down to 4 seconds, which is much more reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest checking out what's doing the work for those seconds (CPU usage), is it mysql or is it your code or something else. You might also consider using `EXPLAIN` to see what's happening in one or the other case and compare those.

Comment: Finally able to test: CPU usage is at 50%, entirely on my application (I'm actually running MySQL on a VirtualPC on the same box, so I'd be able to see if that's working hard as well, and it isn't, at all). Explain shows that it's a SIMPLE select_type, the key it's using, and the Extra column shows "Using where". Not sure what else to look at now, though.

Comment: Although this doesn't exactly answer the question as asked, it led me in the right direction, which is good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problem before using ADO.NET vs the SQL Server Query Analyzer.  When we ran a query from Query Analyzer the query executed subsecond, when we ran it from our web app it was taking upwards of 2 minutes.  For whatever reason applying indexes to the table seemed to speed up data connection between our app and the database.

I don't know the operational differences between MySQl and SQL Server, but another thing that seemed to be happening in our case was that the execution cache was filled up and that was slowing execution on all uncached execution plans way down.  We implemented a weekly job that clears that cache.

Comment: I'll check that when I get back to work. Perhaps there's a way to tell it not to hit the execution cache (something like SQL_NO_CACHE during a select)?

Comment: Doing SQL_NO_CACHE got it down to about 14 seconds, which is better, but still not great.